# SpringBoot projects properties not getting picked up by beans in XML Config

Tags: spring-boot, properties, javabeans

I have a SpringBoot Project and everything works fine locally. Now i have created a runnable jar and trying to execute it.
Project is failing to startup as the beans defined in Spring XML config are not picking up properties defined in property files.
These xml configs are not my own but imported from team libraries so i cannot edit them.

Can someone please advise on what can be done to make it work.

Following are the annotations used in Application.java file. I am not able to add @EnableAutoConfiguration as its implicit and i canot add it here.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        JmxAutoConfiguration.class,
        JmsAutoConfiguration.class,
        ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=RequestReducingAspect.class)})
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode= AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving= EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
```

Edit:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring-valuation-operations.xml","classpath:spring-trade-info.xml","classpath:spring-ib-valuation-api-service.xml","classpath:caching.xml","classpath:applicationContext-valuations-addin.xml","classpath:regtest-common.xml"})
public class TradeSprayerContext {



}
```

Comment: I don't see an import of xml anywhere.

Comment: @M.Deinum XML configs are imported in a separate file. Included that in description.

Comment: You don't need the `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. I'm also not sure how things fail, how are you loading things? What is the error you get etc?

Comment: I am loading properties via PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Error is simply failure to initialize bean due to property not being available.

Comment: Why are you loading them through the `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`? JUst add an `@PropertySource` or let Spring Boot load them.

Comment: We are actually using EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer , because we have some encrypted properties which need to be decrypted.